# How to delete all entries from a table in mySQL and replace them with values from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'usersas6' and I want to delete its entries and replace them with data from table 'base'. The attributes are the same.

```
public function refresh()
    {
      // refresh all the values 
      $this->db->query("DELETE FROM usersas6");
      $this->db->query("UPDATE usersas6, base SET usersas6.password = base.password AND usersas6.accesslevel = base.accesslevel WHERE usersas6.compid = base.compid");

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of INSERT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by executing the following queries:

```
DELETE FROM usersas6;
INSERT INTO usersas6 SELECT * FROM base;
```

But be careful, the two tables must have the same attribute types in the same order respectively.